# How to find a list of all User Security principals (users/user groups) for each folder in SAP BusinessObjects 3.1

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

In BO 3.1 CMC, if you right click a folder then "User Security" you get a list of users and user groups with an associated access level. What is the simplest way to automate the extraction of these to a flat file? They are simply to many to manually go get them.

I have access to the Query Builder and if I have to I'll fire up good old eclipse and hack away at the BO 3.1 SDK.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In XIr2, there was a Security Viewer application that would do what you ask; but it was not provided for XI3.

Since you're familiar with the SDK, you can use [this script on the BOB Forum](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=170766) to generate an extract of security rights.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up simply learning the SDK and extract the information myself. But I wish I saw this before. I might have saved some time.